# OpenGL invalid framebuffer operation after glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

Tags: qt, opengl, error-handling, osx-lion, framebuffer

Every time after I call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`, I get the OpenGL error "invalid framebuffer operation".

The call seems to work just fine, and nothing seems wrong. I call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` first thing in the `::paintGL()` method.

Huh? Should I just disregard this error?

Comment: @cbamber85: no, but I've just put in a `glClearColor(0,0,0,0)` to see if it made any difference, and the other is still there.

Comment: Very possibly the error has been raised by a previous OpenGL call that the code didn't check. Verify that all OpenGL operations are guarded by error checking.

Comment: @StefanHanke: the call to `glClear()` has error-checking code before and after. The error is not set directly before, and it is set directly after. Clearly it's the `glClear()` call that is the culprit.

Comment: Does the code use FBOs for some rendering?

Comment: @StefanHanke: for now, no, it's just a simple program drawing some GL_QUADS.

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you using?

Comment: @cbamber85: 1.7.7 (the default version bundled with Mac OS X Lion).

Comment: @houbysoft I don't know what that number is, but it can't be OpenGL.  On Linux, you would type `glxinfo` and look at `OpenGL version string` - you'll have to search for MacOS equivalent.  For example, my says: `4.2.0 NVIDIA 295.49`, which is the version number, vendor, and driver version.

Comment: @cbamber85: I took that 1.7.7 from the bundle plist. Anyway, running `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version string"` gives `2.1 APPLE-7.18.18`.

Comment: Could also be a driver bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241786/

Answer (score 5):

My best guess is that your framebuffer is not complete and calling `glClear` on an incomplete framebuffer is throwing the error.

Check the status of the framebuffer using `glCheckFramebufferStatus` and make sure it returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`.

Comment: I got the same error as the original poster, and I verified my framebuffers **are** complete. I'm running OpenGL-ES3 on iPhone and the texture which is being cleared is an sRGB-texture - when changing that to a normal "rgb"-texture, the "invalid framebuffer operation" error on glClear stops. From the info given by the OP I can't tell if this is the same in this case, but either way this may provide a hint to someone else running into this issue.

Comment: Update: in my case srgb8 isn't supported as "ColorRenderable" (using GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8 as an alternative works). As James said, glCheckFrameBufferStatus **should** have returned an error, but it doesn't, meaning there is a bug in the openGL implementation I'm using ( OpenGL-ES3 in xcode 7.3 on osx).

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue on osx using NSOpenGLView with a CVDisplayLink to trigger the render callback.

Be sure to wait for the NSOpenGLView to be **fully displayed** before starting rendering, i.e. :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidAppear];

    CVDisplayLinkStart(_displayLink);
}
```

Doing it in viewDidLoad is too early.