# Invalid framebuffer operation after glCheckFramebufferStatus

Tags: opengl, intel, opengl-3

I am getting a weird OpenGL error when running my application on my HD4000 (Windows 64bit, driver version 15.28.20.64.3347).

I boiled it down to a few OpenGL calls to reproduce it:

1. Create two framebuffer objects.
2. Create a texture and bind it as GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 to both FBOs.
3. Call glTexImage2D a second time on the texture
4. Bind the first FBO and call glCheckFramebufferStatus (returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE).
5. Bind the second FBO and call glClear. The glClear gives an GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION.

Step 3 and 4 are required to reproduce the error, which I find especially disturbing for the glCheckFramebufferStatus call. The problem also does not occur on other graphics cards (including the Nvidia card on the same machine).

If you call glCheckFramebufferStatus on the second FBO, it also returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE. However, when inspecting the internal OpenGL state with apitrace, it says that the second FBO has now a color attachment with object name zero.

Re-binding the texture to the second FBO after the glCheckFramebufferStatus call resolves the error. This is working as a workaround for now, but I suppose that binding textures to various FBOs each frame is not a good idea.

Here is the C++ code that reproduces the error:

```cpp
// Create a texture and bind it to two FBOs
GLuint textureName;
glGenTextures(1, &textureName); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, textureName); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL_RGBA, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL); 

GLuint fboNames[2];
glGenFramebuffers(2, fboNames); 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboNames[0]); 
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, textureName, 0); 

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboNames[1]);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, textureName, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, textureName); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL_RGBA, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL); 

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboNames[0]); 

// Removing this line resolves the error
glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); // Returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboNames[1]);
GLenum bufferTarget = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0;
glDrawBuffers(1, &bufferTarget);

// Adding this line resolves the error 
// glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 1, 0); 

glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); // Returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE

//This call causes a GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION error.
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Here is a minimal Visual Studio 2013 Project to reproduce it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5142j26d839gkp9/HD4000Error.zip

Now, my question is: Am I doing something illegal with OpenGL here or is this simply a driver bug?

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this. The code was originally exported from an apitrace dump, that is why the object name was hard coded and the glDrawBuffers was missing. I applied the changes, the result is the same.

Comment: Is there any reason you are re-allocating your texture in this example? After you bind `fboNames [1]`, you have another call to `glTexImage2D (...)`. Also, do you really need a texture rectangle here? They used to have a real purpose (non-power-of-two texturing / unnormalized texture coordinates), but now hardware supports non-power-of-two textures as `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and you can use unnormalized texture coordinates in GLSL 1.30 using `texelFetch (...)`. You are using a power-of-two texture, so I can only guess you need the unnormalized coordinates?

Comment: Have you tried gDEBugger?

Comment: @Andon: The result is the same with GL_TEXTURE_2D. A depth attachment with a depth component texture also produces the same error.

As mentioned in the question text, the error goes away when leaving the second glTexImage2D call. The code is not an excerpt from an actual application, but is the minimal set of calls left over from a apitrace dump with 4k gl calls.

Comment: @Jean-Simon: I used apitrace for debugging. It says that after the first glCheckFramebufferStatus call, the second framebuffer has a color attachment with object name zero.

Comment: @LukasBoersma: Right, but I am starting to think that this is an errant situation created by re-allocating the texture. If you remove the second call to `glTexImage2D (...)`, does the problem go away?

Comment: Longshot here, can you bind the same texture as the color buffer of 2 FBO?

Comment: @Andon: Yes, the error goes away when leaving out the second glTexImage2D call. I guess I could rewrite my application to only call it once, but according to the OpenGL specs, this should be no problem, right? Calling glTexImage2D multiple times is something that I do quite often, for streaming animated textures and so on.

Comment: @Jean-Simon: I am pretty sure this is possible. I frequently use the same texture in multiple FBOs. For example in a long chain of post processes, It would be impossible to allocate memory for each post process.

Comment: @LukasBoersma: That is fine, and the reason you would use `glTexImage2D (...)` to stream a texture rather than `glTexSubImage2D (...)` is to prevent [implicit synchronizaiton](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Synchronization#Implicit_synchronization). I think this is a driver bug, re-allocating the storage for your texture should be something that the FBO knows about immediately; for some reason it seems you have to re-attach it for the driver to know about the re-allocation. Rather than avoiding re-allocating textures, you might consider re-attaching them whenever you do this.

Comment: @Andon: That sounds like a plausible cause for the problem. I still don't know why the glCheckFramebufferStatus breaks everything, but I don't think there is a logical explanation for it. I'll contact Intel about this issue and see if they agree this is a driver bug. Until then I'll keep the workaround to re-attach the textures. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We reported this issue to Intel and it seems that it was in fact a bug. It is fixed in the current driver version.